# Tic Tac Toe diagonal check

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm building a game of Tic-Tac-Toe, and I have a vertical and horizontal check that look like this:

```
def check_win_left_vert (board):
    win = True
    x = 0
    for y in range (2):
        if board[y][x] != board[y+1][x]:
            win = False
    return win
```

It looks through the board by incrementing the y axis; I use the same method for the x axis. How would I do this for a diagonal axis? Would I increment both?

Comment: There are only eight lines to check, so it's much simpler to create a list of tuples of the relevant indexes, and then iterate over that to pull out the board values: `XYZ = [(0,1,2), (3,4,5), ... ]; for x, y, z in XYZ: if board[x] == board[y] == board[z]: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same variable for both on one diagonal, and "2 invert" it on the other:

```
for x in range(2):
    if board[x][x] ...

for x in range(2):
    if board[x][2-x] ...
```

Note that you have to watch out for boundary conditions.  I strongly suspect that you haven't bothered to test your horizontal code yet, as it tries to check a space off the right edge of the board.  Reduce the range to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make in the same loop check for diagonal case

```
    if board[y][y] != board[y+1][y+1] or board[2-y][y] != board[1-y][1+y]:
        win = False
    if win == False:
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### All checks with list comprehensions

```py
game_board = [ [1, 0, 1],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0] ]

# Horizontals
h = [str(i+1) + ' Row' for i, v in enumerate(game_board) if sum(v) == 3]

# Verticals
v = [str(i+1) + ' Col' for i in range(3) if sum([j[i] for j in game_board]) == 3]

# Diagonals
d = [['Left Diag', '','Right Diag'][i+1] for i in [-1, 1] if sum([game_board[0][1+i], game_board[1][1]], game_board[2][1-i]) == 3]

if any([h,v,d]):
    print('You won on:', h, v, d)
else:
    print('No win yet')
```