# How to check if a column or row (or diagonal) are all equal in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a dictionary:

```
squares = {
          'r1c1':{'location':[0,0,150,150],'status':'o'},
          'r1c2':{'location':[150,0,300,150],'status':None},
          'r1c3':{'location':[300,0,450,150],'status':None},
          'r2c1':{'location':[0,150,150,300],'status':'x'},
          'r2c2':{'location':[150,150,300,300],'status':'x'},
          'r2c3':{'location':[300,150,450,300],'status':'x'},
          'r3c1':{'location':[0,300,150,450],'status':None},
          'r3c2':{'location':[150,300,300,450],'status':None},
          'r3c3':{'location':[300,300,450,450],'status':'o'}
          }
```

Ignore location. R stands for row; C stands for column. I want to know if there is a compact function I can use to check if all all rows, columns, or diagonals have the same value ... think TicTacToe ... As of now, I have it all in a big if statement:

```
def TicTacToe(self):
    #rows
    if self.squares['r1c1']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r1c2']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r1c3']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')
    elif self.squares['r2c1']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r2c3']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')
    elif self.squares['r3c1']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r3c2']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r3c3']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')

    elif self.squares['r1c1']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r1c2']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r1c3']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
    elif self.squares['r2c1']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r2c3']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
    elif self.squares['r3c1']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r3c2']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r3c3']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
    #columns
    elif self.squares['r1c1']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r2c1']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r3c1']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')
    elif self.squares['r1c2']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r3c2']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')
    elif self.squares['r1c3']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r2c3']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r3c3']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')

    elif self.squares['r1c1']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r2c1']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r3c1']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
    elif self.squares['r1c2']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r3c2']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
    elif self.squares['r1c3']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r2c3']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r3c3']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
    #diagonal
    elif self.squares['r1c1']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r3c3']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')
    elif self.squares['r1c3']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'x' and self.squares['r3c1']['status'] == 'x':
        self.gameOver('x')
    elif self.squares['r1c1']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r3c3']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
    elif self.squares['r1c3']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r2c2']['status'] == 'o' and self.squares['r3c1']['status'] == 'o':
        self.gameOver('o')
```

But this is ugly and I want to do better. Any ideas?...

Comment: In Python, functions, class methods and variables are named using `lowercase_with_underscores`, note `camelCase` or `CapitalCase`. The latter is used for `class WhateverClass` and the former isn't used.

Comment: step 1) convert your board into some better representation like a list of lists instead of what you have. Step 2) take your pick: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/tic-tac-toe-victory-check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215893/beginner-tic-tac-toe-game-for-python https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230212/simulate-tic-tac-toe-game-in-python https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/tic-tac-toe-victory-check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423891/tic-tac-toe-diagonal-check

Comment: Are you implying I should use tic_tac_toe  or ticTacToe, instead of TicTacToe with the first comment? Or are you saying something else, and it's going over my head?

Comment: `def tic_tac_toe(squares):` . (I changed the argument name from `self` because you shouldn't name arguments `self` unless it's the first argument of a [class method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes), you can use the name `squares` again if you just call this function like `tic_tac_toe(squares)`)

Comment: Yes, it's within a class. I just didn't include the whole program for simplicity sake. But thanks for the tip!!!

Answer (score 2):

First, convert `squares` to something better, like this

```
board = [[squares[f"r{row}c{col}"]["status"] for row in range(1, 4)] for col in range(1, 4)]
```

now `board` is a list of lists:

```
[[ 'o', 'x', None], 
 [None, 'x', None], 
 [None, 'x',  'o']]
```

You can now use any of the thousands of code samples that exist for this problem:

```
def check_columns(board):
    for column in board:
        if len(set(column)) == 1 and column[0] is not None:
            return column[0]

def check_rows(board):
    return check_columns(zip(*reversed(board)))  # rotate the board 90 degrees

def check_diagonals(board):
    if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]) or
        (board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2])):
        if board[1][1] is not None:
            return board[1][1]

def who_won(board):
    for check in [check_columns, check_rows, check_diagonals]:
        result = check(board)
        if result is not None:
            return result
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> who_won(board)
'x'
>>> board[1][1] = 'o'
>>> who_won(board)
'o'
>>> board[1][1] = None
>>> who_won(board)
>>> 
>>> # nothing printed means it returned `None` (because there's no winner)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347043/how-can-i-rotate-this-list-of-lists-with-python for what `zip(*board)` does

Comment: also, I might've confused rows and columns, depending on how you look at it. It really doesn't matter though, because tic-tac-toe is completely symmetrical anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution for a NxN dimensional square board.

```py
squares = {
    'r1c1':{'location':[0,0,150,150],'status':'o'},
    'r1c2':{'location':[150,0,300,150],'status':None},
    'r1c3':{'location':[300,0,450,150],'status':None},
    'r2c1':{'location':[0,150,150,300],'status':'x'},
    'r2c2':{'location':[150,150,300,300],'status':'x'},
    'r2c3':{'location':[300,150,450,300],'status':'x'},
    'r3c1':{'location':[0,300,150,450],'status':None},
    'r3c2':{'location':[150,300,300,450],'status':None},
    'r3c3':{'location':[300,300,450,450],'status':'o'}
}
N = 3 # Assuming you have NxN dimensional board
def check_rows():
    # Check for all rows
    for i in range(N):
        row = 'r'+str(i+1)
        flag = True
        # Check if all value in current row are NOT 'x' or 'o'
        for j in range(N-1):
            cell1 = row+'c'+str(j+1)
            cell2 = row+'c'+str(j+2)
            if squares[cell1]['status'] != squares[cell2]['status']:
                flag = False
                break
        if flag: # All values are same
            print('Found match in',row)
            return True
    return False # No match
def check_cols():
    # Check for all cols
    for i in range(N):
        col = 'c'+str(i+1)
        flag = True
        # Check if all value in current col are NOT 'x' or 'o'
        for j in range(N-1):
            cell1 = 'r'+str(j+1)+col
            cell2 = 'r'+str(j+2)+col
            if squares[cell1]['status'] != squares[cell2]['status']:
                flag = False
                break
        if flag: # All values are same
            print('Found match in',col)
            return True
    return False # No match
def check_left_diag():
    flag = True
    # Check if all value in left diagonal are NOT 'x' or 'o'
    for i in range(N-1):
        cell1 = 'r'+str(i+1)+'c'+str(i+1)
        cell2 = 'r'+str(i+2)+'c'+str(i+2)
        if squares[cell1]['status'] != squares[cell2]['status']:
            flag = False
            break
    if flag: # All values are same
        print('Found match in left diagonal')
        return True
    return False # No match
def check_right_diag():
    flag = True
    # Check if all value in right diagonal are NOT 'x' or 'o'
    for i in range(N-1):
        cell1 = 'r'+str(i+1)+'c'+str(N-i)
        cell2 = 'r'+str(i+2)+'c'+str(N-i-1)
        if squares[cell1]['status'] != squares[cell2]['status']:
            flag = False
            break
    if flag: # All values are same
        print('Found match in right diagonal')
        return True
    return False # No match

print(check_rows())
print(check_cols())
print(check_left_diag())
print(check_right_diag())
```

Output

```
Found match in r2
True
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an even shorter way to check the results of a tic-tac-toe game by creating a [generator](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators), `lines()` that yields all 8 lines (3 rows, 3 columns and 2 diagonals) and then checking if any of them is made up of only one element and that element isn't `None`

Once you've got something like

```
board = [
    [ 'o', 'x', None], 
    [None, 'x', None], 
    [None, 'x',  'o']
]
```

Do this:

```
def _rows_and_diagonal(board):
    yield from board  # the rows
    yield [board[i][i] for i in range(len(board))]  # one of the diagonals

def lines(board):
    yield from _rows_and_diagonal(board)
    # rotate the board 90 degrees to get the columns and the other diagonal
    yield from _rows_and_diagonal(list(zip(*reversed(board))))

def who_won(board):
    for line in lines(board):
        if len(set(line)) == 1 and line[0] is not None:
            return line[0]
    return None  # if we got this far, there's no winner
```

This will work for any sized tic-tac-toe board, not just 3×3.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check_win():
  #Horizontal Algo
  for row in game:
      check_win2(row)
check_win2(horcheck)
check = []
  #Vertical algo
  for col in range(len(game[0])):
      check = []
      for row in game:
          check.append(row[col])
      check_win2(check)
  #Diagonal Algo
  rev_diags = []
  diags = []
  cols = list(reversed(range(len(game))))
  rows = range(len(game))
  for col, row in zip(cols, rows):
    rev_diags.append(col)
    diags.append(row)
  check_win2(rev_diags)
  check_win2(diags)

def check_win2(lists):
  if lists.count(lists[0]) == len(lists) and lists[0] != 0:
    print(f'Player {lists[0]} won the game')
    exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

With your current setup this would be very difficult to achieve. I don't think a dictionary alone would be a good idea. What you would need is a **2 dimensional matrix** of dictionary object containing *location* and *status*. This way you can very easily iterate on the row and the column of your 2d matrix with two for loop and check the status of each cells.

Comment: I don't yet know what a  2 dimensional matrix is, but I'm going to look it up - thank you very much, friend! (Edit: nvm, you mean a list of lists ...)

Comment: think about it as a list that contain other list of the same size. So if you want to make a 2 dimensional matrix of height and width = 3 it will look like this:
`matrix = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],]`